# I wrote such a member function in Clion, why does the IDE prompt to add const here?

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

As above.Thanks for your help!

I wrote such a member function in Clion, why does the IDE prompt to add const here?
[image]

Comment: It's called "static analysis": it helps you write better code.

Comment: Are you asking what `const` means for a class member function? Or are you asking why your IDE added it in this particular case?

Comment: its because C++ initially got the defaults wrong. Mainly due to historic reasons. A nice example is lambdas whose `operator()` is `const` unless you declare it as `mutable`. If you dont understand a word of that, read about "const correctness"

Comment: I don't know why the IDE added it in this particular case？